# Permission denied to execute a .sh file when trying to install a software from a CD

Tags: command-line, permissions, realtek

I have a few questions about the software I'm about to install. The receiver(USB) is by Quantum(qhmpl) and the software is by Realtek. It's available for different OS. BTW, I'm installing it from the CD. In linux, there's a .sh file and I'm unable to give permission; says permission denied. So, I want to know how to give permission, if possible and is it safe to execute a file from the CD? I've read somewhere that it could be a virus, but since it's from realtek, it must be safe, right?

[image]

Comment: what happens if you call it from terminal running the command 'sh install.sh' or 'bash install.sh' from the directory where the CD is mounted? Do this only if you know exactly what the script really does. Nevertheless, if you have doubts about the script, you can open it in an editor to check its content

Comment: I haven't used that command yet. I only know that It executes a program. Other than that, I'm not sure. >  you can open it in an editor to check its content. I'm not sure what do you mean by that.

Comment: Check the CD for something like a "readme" file. I guess Realtek would have documented the installation procedure somewhere.

Comment: It just says to run `install.sh` script like what @chili555 said in the answer below. https://imgur.com/a/hzBBuRm

Comment: Nobody has pointed out that the software discs distributed with hardware, usually have old, outdated software on them. You should probably find out what kind of USB receiver/wireless that you're installing, and look for a newer driver, either at Realtek, or elsewhere. Otherwise, adding `sudo` to your command may allow it to install from your current disc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the software is burned into the CD and finalized, its permissions, in this case, Read Only, are fixed. You can drag and drop the software to your desktop and then, from the terminal, do:

```
cd ~/Desktop/software_folder
sudo chmod +x install.sh
```

And install it with:

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

As @LorenzKeel very aptly suggests, if you have the slightest doubt as to the origin or integrity of the software, you may examine it with:

```
less install.sh
```

Get out of 'less' with q.

Comment: You don't need `sudo` to `chmod` a file you own. Also, since you don't know the contents of the file, I wouldn't suggest running it with root privileges. Maybe it doesn't even need it and using sudo may mess up permissions.

Comment: You mean, I should copy all the content from the CD to my desktop and then I should go and execute the .sh file there on the desktop and not on the CD itself?

Comment: @danzel so I should do `sudo ./install.sh` directly?

Comment: "execute the .sh file there on the desktop and not on the CD itself" Yes, exactly.